# how to remove selected list element, instead of removing only top li tag

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to remove specific li elements, based off of which one has the x button clicked. Currently I'm having an error

"bZMQWNZvyQeA:42 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'."

I am aware that this could mean that the paramater is null, but this dosn't make any sense to me. Chrome dev tools show that the onClick attribute is correctly exectuing removeItem, and passing in the idName as a parameter. How is this not working?

```
var note = 0;

function saveInfo() {
  var idName = "note" + note;
  //assign text from input box to var text, and store in local storage
  var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
  var text = localStorage.setItem(note, input);
  var list = document.createElement("li");
  var node = document.createTextNode(input);
  var removeBtn = document.createElement("button");

  list.setAttribute("id", idName);
  removeBtn.setAttribute("onClick", `removeItem(${idName})`);
  removeBtn.innerHTML = "X";
  list.appendChild(node);
  list.appendChild(removeBtn);
  document.getElementById("output").appendChild(list);

  note += 1;
}

function removeItem(name) {
  var parent = document.getElementById("output");
  var child = document.getElementById(name);
  parent.removeChild(child);
}
```

Comment: Here's another approach: don't use inline JS binding by setting the `onclick` attribute. Instead. listen to the click even bubbling up from the button, and catch it on the level of `#output`. Then, find the `<li>` parent node of the event target and delete it.

Comment: This sounds like a good approach. I'm a bit of a js noob yet though, and I'm not quite sure how to implement that. Specifically, what do you mean when you say "catch it on the level of output"? I'm pretty sure I get how to do the rest, but I don't understand that part.

Comment: Sure thing. I have posted an answer that hopefully will help you understand event bubbling better.

Comment: Ok I figured it out, thanks @Terry. The solution, for anyone who might see this, was to remove 
`removeBtn.setAttribute("onClick", ` `removeItem(${idName})` `);`

I also removed the removeItem function, as the new solution is simpler.

I then added  

`document.addEventListener('click', function (event){
    if(event.target.matches('.removeBtn')){
       event.target.parentNode.remove();
       };
  });`

This was the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my comment, I suggested that you listen to click event bubbling from the `removeBtn`. In this case, all you need is to remove the `onclick` attribute assignment logic from your code, and instead give your `removeButton` an identifiable property, such as a class. Lets give it a class of `delete-button`:

```
var removeBtn = document.createElement("button");
removeBtn.classList.add('delete-button');
removeBtn.type = 'button';
removeBtn.innerHTML = 'X';
```

Then, you can listen to the click event at the level of `#output`, which is guaranteed to be present at runtime. When the event is fired, you simply check if the event target has the identifiable property, e.g. the `remove-button` class in our case:

```
output.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  // GUARD: Do nothing if click event does not originate from delete button
  if (!e.target.matches('.remove-button')) {
    return;
  }

  // Delete parent node
  e.target.closest('li').remove();
});
```

If the click event did not originate from the remove button, we simply `return` and don't do anything else. Otherwise, we know that the button has been clicked, and we can then use [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest), i.e. `.closest('li')` to retrieve the closest `<li>` parent node and delete it.

If you absolutely have to support IE11 (which in turn, does not support `Element.closest()`), you can also use [`Node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) to access and delete the `<li>` element, assuming that your remove button is a direct child of the `<li>` element:

```
// Delete parent node
e.target.parentNode.remove();
```

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
var rows = 10;
var output = document.getElementById('output');

for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  var list = document.createElement('li');
  var node = document.createTextNode('Testing. Row #' + i);
  var removeBtn = document.createElement("button");
  removeBtn.classList.add('remove-button');
  removeBtn.type = 'button';
  removeBtn.innerHTML = 'X';
  
  list.appendChild(node);
  list.appendChild(removeBtn);
  
  output.appendChild(list);
}

output.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  // GUARD: Do nothing if click event does not originate from delete button
  if (!e.target.matches('.remove-button')) {
    return;
  }
  
  e.target.closest('li').remove();
});
```

```html
<ul id="output"></ul>
```

Comment: I ended up doing something quite similar to this. I used parentNode instead of closest. Is one of those more semantically correct?

And thankfully this code is destined for a chrome extension, built for a learning project. Chose this so I can intentionally avoid cross browser support, since that isn't what I'm focused on learning right now.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: @QuintenSteenwyk `Element.closest()` is useful when you do not know how deeply the button is nested, it's functionally equivalent to jQuery's `.closest()`. In this case, since you're 100% sure of the DOM structure, you can safely use `Node.parentNode` instead :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have missing quotes around the id that you pass to `removeItem`:

```
removeBtn.setAttribute("onClick", `removeItem(${idName})`);
```

This should be:

```
removeBtn.setAttribute("onClick", `removeItem('${idName}')`);
```

#### Better pattern

It is better practice to bind the click handler without relying on string evaluation of code, and without needing to create dynamic `id` attribute values:

```
removeBtn.addEventListener("click", () => removeItem(list));
```

And then the function `removeItem` should expect the node itself, not the id:

```
function removeItem(child) {
  child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
}
```

You can remove the following code:

```
var idName = "note" + note;
list.setAttribute("id", idName);
```

Comment: Actually, the `var idName = "note" + note;` is there primarily for naming the keys in the local storage. That being said, you mentioned this isn't best practice. Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: I did not see in your question how else you used `idName`, but if you do use it, then keep it. However, there is always another way to do it. It could possibly be the topic of a new question. ;-)